# Find sibling node after specified node is found

Tags: xpath

Consider the following very simplified example.

```
<n></n>
<k></k>
<m></m>
<k></k>
```

How can I search for a first `k` sibling after `m` node? Basically, find some node and then continue searching from that node.

Comment: Why have the answer from @Neil and its comments disappeared ?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

> How can I search for a first `k` sibling after `m` node? Basically, find
>   some node and then continue searching from that node.

Assuming that we have the following well-formed XML document:

```
<t>
    <n></n>
    <k></k>
    <m></m>
    <k></k>
</t>
```

**then the following XPath expression**:

```
/*/m[1]/following-sibling::k[1]
```

selects the first `k` following-sibling of the first `m` child of the top element of the XML document.

Comment: @Anthony Your question is not clear. Please, provide an XML document. And why not ask a real SO question? Many people will be able to provide a good answer.

Comment: in other words how can i select any sibling that matches a condition?

Comment: @anthony: `(preceding-sibling::node()[yourCondition] | following-sibling::node()[yourCondition])[1]`    This selects the first (in document order) node in the context of which yourCondition is `true()`  This can be written shorter if you can use XPath 2.0 or higher

Comment: how do i check which version of XPATH i'm using??

Comment: Just try to evaluate an XPath 2.0 expression (one that has syntax that is supported only in XPath 2.0) For example `if( 5 gt 3) then 'Greater' else 'LessOrEqual'`

Answer (score 4):

nice question : try it ........

```
<a>
<n></n>
<k></k>
<m></m>
<k></k> <====
<k></k>
<m></m>
<k></k>
</a>


   /a/k[. = preceding::m][1]
```

Comment: This answer is interesting, but it starts from **the first "m" having a "k" after it**, not from **the current node**.

Comment: Also, is that `preceding::m` bit a back-reference? Wouldn't that be less performant than a solution which looks for `m` first? (Don't know)